# Make 2d array list of points

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a method that adds 2d points to a list but I ned them to be in a 2d format like: [3,2].  Right now it only gives[3,0,1,3]  which are all different points but they are only half of those points.This is what my initialized list looks like: `List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();`. and here is the out put, 3,0,1,3. It needs to be [3,1],[0,1] and so on. How can i fix this? Here is my code for this:

```
public List<Integer> getNeighbors(int[][] boards, int x, int y) {
    //the list of neighbor nodes
    ArrayList<Point> neighbors = new ArrayList<Point>();
    if (x > 0){
        neighbors.add(boards[x-1][ y]);
    }
    if (y > 0){
        neighbors.add(boards[x][y-1]);
    }
    if (x < q){
        neighbors.add(boards[x+1][y]);
    }
    if (y < q){
        neighbors.add(boards[x][y+1]);
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Code please, so that we can suggest changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use 
`List<Point> neighbors = ArrayList<Point>()` 
or use an 
`ArrayList<YourClass>`
 where YourClass has two int fields.

Comment: so where would I change that and do I have to change what I am doing in the method for it to work?

Comment: Wherever is necessary.

Comment: right now it says that it cannot add the ints to a point list.

Comment: No, you must add only Points to a Points List.